# Sum of Int from stringValue

Tags: ios, swift, integer, double, alamofire

I am parsing data from mysql into my IOS swift app using Alamofire, the data are Integers, and I am fetching them into text fields then I will do some calculations on them,
I loaded the data Successful but the issue that they cann't be assigned to the text fields!

```
func getIcomeData() {
    start()
    let url = URLs.income
    AF.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("Validation Successful)")

                if let json = response.data {
                    do{
                        let jsonData = try JSON(data: json)
                        let dataarray = jsonData.arrayValue
                        print("DATA PARSED: \(jsonData)")
                        for itemDict in dataarray{

                            let int1 = itemDict["Base-Pay-Monthly"].intValue
                            **self.BPMTXT.text = itemDict["Base-Pay-Monthly"].intValue**
                            
                            let int2 = itemDict["Overtime"].intValue
                            **self.OTTXT.text = itemDict["Overtime"].intValue**
                                    
                                                       
                            let int6 = itemDict["Others"].intValue
                            **self.OthersTXT.text = itemDict["Others"].intValue**
                            
                            let totalIncome = [int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6]
                            let sum = totalIncome.reduce(0, +)
                            //self.NetPayLabel.text = String(sum)
                            self.NetPay = Double(sum)
                            
                            
                        }
                        self.stop()
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("JSON Error", error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

}

I am getting this error Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String' on the bolded lines

Comment: You should convert `Int` to `String`.  `self.BPMTXT.text = String(itemDict["Base-Pay-Monthly"].intValue)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very clear.

`self.BPMTXT.text` is String.
`itemDict["Base-Pay-Monthly"].intValue` is Int.
Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String'

Try the following modifications.

```
self.BPMTXT.text = "\(itemDict["Base-Pay-Monthly"].intValue)"

self.OTTXT.text = "\(itemDict["Overtime"].intValue)"

self.OthersTXT.text = "\(itemDict["Others"].intValue)"
```